# Cannot Access Web Page on Apache 2.2 Server

Tags: html, apache

I've made a simple web page for one of my classes, and uploaded it to an Apache server on campus, from which I'm to view and take a screenshot of.

Before trying to view the page I created a sub-directory on the server to put my HTML file. Once the upload was complete, I changed the permissions on the file to `-rwx---r-x` and on the sub-directory folder to `drwx---r-x`.

However, I'm not able to view the page. I keep getting a message saying `403: Forbidden. You do not have sufficient privileges to view this site on this server`.

Is there anything else that I need to do to the file and/or folder to be able to view the web page?

Comment: Server Config is Off-Topic for Stack Overflow!

Comment: Wrong place. I suggest you post your question in the correct site, and you would get better help. As for your server error, you have the files or folders you messed with, with the wrong permissions or owner. Some setups will fail to run if the file is not the correct permission or owner.

Answer (score 0):

Who is the owner and the group of the file?

You probably need to change the file permissions to `-rwxr--r--` and directory to `drwxr-xr-x`